# Помогите разобраться с REAT API на PHP

Tags: php, json, xml, валидация, rest

Есть такая задача:

Build API to validate payment information

Requirements:
Rest API
Needs to support data in 2 formats: JSON and XML
Needs to authorize request hash from the key, data and timestamp

Supported payment types:
Credit card number
Expiration date
CVV2
Email
Mobile
Phone number

Validation:
Credit card:  Credit card number based on Luhn's algorithm
Expiration date
CVV2
Email
Mobile
Phone number format

Response:
Valid: bool
Error code: list of error codes based on validation

Not allowed using of any open source libs or/and frameworks.

Я уже много теории начитался про Rest API, но никогда раньше на практике не видел как это делается.
Я думал сделать так:
при отправки запроса, например, http://example.com/check.php?id=1&format=json c бд вытягивается строка с id=1 и данные из этой строки проверяются на валидность. После проверки возвращается результат в формате json (типа {"bool":true} или {"bool":false}). Если отправить http://example.com/check.php?id=1&format=xml, то все так же только ответ будет в xml.
 1. Скажите, пожалуйста, я правильно все понимаю или нет? И если нет, то как правильно все сделать, что прочитать и в чем разобраться получше?
 2. И как это понять "Needs to authorize request hash from the key, data and timestamp"? Что за authorize request и для чего он здесь нужен?
 Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Скажите, пожалуйста, я правильно все понимаю или нет?

Ну не совсем

> И как это понять "Needs to authorize request hash from the key, data
>   and timestamp"?

Ну вы сами подумайте вы даёте в GET просто id и формат, значит я могу перебрать все GET-запросы 1,2,3,4,5 то я могу вытянуть всех юзеров из системы. Далее. В БД уже должны быть только валидные данные, значит прверять на валидность надо когда их кладём в БД. Тут-то нам и пригодится архитектура REST потому что класть можно не GET и не POST а PUT-запросом.
Ок оставновимся на GET-запросах как у ВК например, хотя по-честному это будет уже не REST-API а WEB-API но неважно. Как авторизовтаь пользователя через GET нужно сначала выдать ему ключ, который кроме него никто не знает, а потом проверять этот ключ при каждом запросе. При желании этот ключ можно менять хоть каждый день.

Answer (score 0):

Я тоже новичок в этих ваших интернетах, но постараюсь высказать свое видение по данной технологии. Для гет-пост запроса желательно отправлять ответ только после авторизации. Строго проверяются все пост запросы. Распределение ролей авторизованных получателей. Дамп времени чтобы не отсылать идентичные данные за определенное короткое время и т.д